# Alert Browser version and name at same time i

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to alert of the browser name and version at the same time. But it doesn't seem to work. Anyone can help me?

```
<script>        
function CheckBro() {
if (window.chrome) { 
alert ("Your are using  " + (navigator.appName) + " " + (navigator.appVersion) + " & " + (BrowserDetect.browser)  + " " + (BrowserDetect.version) );
}
else { alert('Unknown Browser'); }
};
window.onLoad = CheckBro();
</script>
```

I want if any of the two works i.e BrowserDetect or Navigator.app

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use `+` between the two values, not parentheses around each one

Comment: remove the last } at the end of 3rd line

Comment: You need to learn the basics of Javascript, such as string concatenation.

Comment: I'd suggest you format your code first. There is a blatant syntax error.

Comment: I have solved the syntax error. Now what can i do?

Comment: This behavior is by design.   StackOverflow is not a service to teach you Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
function CheckBro() {
if (window.chrome) { 
alert ( (navigator.appName) + (navigator.appVersion) );}

else { alert('Unknown Browser'); }
};
window.onLoad = CheckBro();
```

Comment: Well, if it worked like a charm, you need to accept this answer, and vote for anything that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

As  Aleks G points out, use '+' to concatenate. Remove the '}' at the end of the 3rd line and make sure BrowserDetect is defined in you code.

```
function CheckBro() {
if (window.chrome) { 
      alert ( (navigator.appName) + (navigator.appVersion) ); 
      alert ( (BrowserDetect.browser) +  (BrowserDetect.version) ); 
} else { alert('Unknown Browser'); }
};
```